# I want to run a python script periodically (every 10 minutes). What options do I have?

Tags: server, raspberry-pi

Basically, I want this script to be able to run regardless of if my computer is on or off. What would be a good approach? I have thought of using a Raspberry pi, and maybe AWS would allow this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a scheduled event using AWS lambda.

Documentation on how to do that:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use cronjobs for that.
See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md